# Python 2.x - Manipulating tuples and concatenating with str type

Tags: string, python-2.7, tuples

I recently wrote a code to work with text analysis, however I have some difficulties in manipulating some data types in python.

I will paste the snippet of the code in which I make this manipulation and soon after I will explain it and put my doubts, if they can help I will be grateful.

```
def classificaTexto(nbc, tweet):

    #textoProcessado = preProcessamentoText(tweet)
    for features in tweet:
        result = nbc.classify(extracaoCaracteristicas(features[0]))
        #return result
        if (result == 4) :
            print 'Crime não categorizado - ' + str(tuple(features))
        elif (result == 1):
            print 'Roubo - ' + str(tuple(features))
        elif(result == 2):
            print 'Homicídio - ' + str(tuple(features))
        elif(result== 3):
            print 'Tráfico - ' + str(tuple(features))
        else :
            print 'Não representa um crime - ' + str(tuple(features))


# Main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Load the files with text - Both are csv    
    carregarTextos()
    test_set()

    # Extract the feature vector of all tweets in one go
    conjuntoTreino = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(extracaoCaracteristicas, tweets)

    # Train the classifier
    NBClassifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(conjuntoTreino)
    classificaTexto(NBClassifier, testset)
```

Now the explanations:

In `classificaTexto(NBClassifier, testset)`, testset is the variable where I read one of the csv files and transform it into a feature vector. The result of this transformation is a tuple with the following result:

```
(['multas', 'caras', 'partir', 'multas', 'caras', 'partir', 'novembro', 'novos', 'previstos', 'partir', 'cujo', 'valor', 'multa', 'atual', 'multas', 'serem', 'pagas', 'grave', 'atuais', 'multas', 'cobradas', 'consideradas', 'leves', 'reajustadas', 'atuais', 'partir', 'novembro', 'reajustados', 'valores', 'multas', 'aplicadas', 'motoristassuspeitos', 'dirigir', 'recusarem', 'teste', 'nesse', 'multa', 'motorista', 'suspensa', 'prazo', 'brasil'], '5')
```

Soon after, the method `classificaTexto`is executed. As you can see above, I read the tuples and then do a print where I have a text (str) and the tuple. The purpose here is to say a feeling that is related to the text contained in the tuple. But the result is this:

```
Não representa um crime - (['multas', 'caras', 'partir', 'multas', 'caras', 'partir', 'novembro', 'novos', 'previstos', 'partir', 'cujo', 'valor', 'multa', 'atual', 'multas', 'serem', 'pagas', 'grave', 'atuais', 'multas', 'cobradas', 'consideradas', 'leves', 'reajustadas', 'atuais', 'partir', 'novembro', 'reajustados', 'valores', 'multas', 'aplicadas', 'motoristassuspeitos', 'dirigir', 'recusarem', 'teste', 'nesse', 'multa', 'motorista', 'suspensa', 'prazo', 'brasil'], '5')
```

My question and doubts are as follows:

1 - This one below is the best way to interact with tuples?

```
for features in tweet:
        result = nbc.classify(extracaoCaracteristicas(features[0]))
```

2 - Is the form I used to concatenate a str type and tuples correct? `print 'Tráfico - ' + str(tuple(features)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding point n°2:
no, the way you concatenate isn't the way you should in order to obtain what you expect.
This should work:

`print 'Trafico - ' + ', '.join(features[0])`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i get this error on output `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found`

Comment: This error means that features is not a list of string but a list containing lists... could you 
        print features
and past the result as a comment ?

Comment: `(['multas', 'caras', 'partir', 'multas', 'caras', 'partir', 'novembro', 'novos', 'previstos', 'partir', 'cujo', 'valor', 'multa', 'atual', 'multas', 'serem', 'pagas', 'grave', 'atuais', 'multas', 'cobradas', 'consideradas', 'leves', 'reajustadas', 'atuais', 'partir', 'novembro', 'reajustados', 'valores', 'multas', 'aplicadas', 'motoristassuspeitos', 'dirigir', 'recusarem', 'teste', 'nesse', 'multa', 'motorista', 'suspensa', 'prazo', 'brasil'], '5')` This is one examples of what  have in features

Comment: Yah, work. Thank You. Despite answering item 2 of my question I will wait to see if anyone else will appreciate answering the other items.

Comment: Concerning point n°1: 
Is the tuple you're refering to ```tweets``` ? Then if the question is is it good practice to do ```for item in tuple: do stuff``` answer is yes.

Concerning point n°3: 
I do not understand your question. the first part of it seems answered with point n°2. The second half of it is not clear to me: what do you mean by: " is equivalent to the feeling of the text to which I will sort"

Comment: Yes, the 3 item was responding along with 2. I edited the question without it to get better. And yes, the tuple is the `tweets`.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Just sayin' you got a typo in your question:

1 - This one **above** is the best way to interact with tuples?

1 - This one **below** is the best way to interact with tuples?

Comment: Yeah. **below**